# How i can get windows logon domain name from AD domain name

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, directoryentry

I have AD domain name like MyDomain.com and Windows logon domain name like MD (MD=MyDomain). How I can get win logon domain name from AD domain using **DirectoryEntry.Properties** collection?

Comment: I found solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/add6bc4d-273f-495a-a7ec-ee29b0fe34bd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you could use this:

```
string username = "<username>";

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomain"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUsername"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"]);

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = string.Format("samaccountname={0}",
    (username.Split('\\').Length > 1) ? username.Split('\\')[1] : username);

SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
if (result == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(
        string.Format("Username '{0}' does not exist in the active directory", username), "username");
```

You can then use the Properties collection on the SearchResult object to get information from the user object (e.g. result.Properties["samaccountname"]). Some useful keys are:

- List item samaccountname (Windows username)
- List item displayName (Full name)
- List item telephoneNumber
- List item mail (email address)
- List item department (the department the user belongs to)